# Updating a MS-Access datatable without primary key in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I have built a datatable with employees, their departments, join date and exit date in the department. Each employee can have more than one department under him. Hence i cannot have a primary key. So how do i write the Update query for this. I am using a DataGridView to update the table. Please help.

Comment: Why would that mean "Hence i cannot have a primary key"?

Answer (score 1):

The only purpose of the primary key is to distinguish one row from another.  That's it.  And you REALLY should have a PK.  You don't even have to display it to the user.  It can be something generic like `Row_Id`.  The point of a PK is that the database uses it as a unique identifier for each row, so it's probably best to just use an auto-incrementing integer.

If you don't have a Primary Key, then you will at least need some sort of Unique Constraint(s) to differentiate one row from the next.  Otherwise, you cannot reliably `SELECT` or `UPDATE` a given row.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously advice you to add `Employee_Id` primary key because it is easy to update with Id (unique). You can't update with name, department, etc..
You can set the primary key of a table by:

```
Dim table As New DataTable()
table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Employee_Id"))
Dim primaryKey(1) As DataColumn
primaryKey(1) = table.Columns("Employee_Id")
table.PrimaryKey = primaryKey
```

and the update by using this `Employee_Id`

Comment: The issue is since one employee can be in multiple departments, in this particular table even the employee_ID will not be unique.

Comment: If so, use two tables with `foreign key` and `primary key`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have multiple tables here. One table with only the employee information, one table with the department information, and one table with the employeeID, departmentID, and the join/exit date. A single table is not going to suffice here.

Fix your database structure before worrying about how to update it.